# Classic ASP Bottlenecks

Tags: sql-server, performance, iis-7, asp-classic

I have 2 websites connecting to the same instance of MSSQL via classic ASP. Both websites are similar in nature and run similar queries.

One website chokes up every once in a while, while the other website is fine. This leads me to believe MSSQL is not the problem, otherwise I would think the bottleneck would occur in both websites simultaneously.

I've been trying to use Performance Monitor in Windows Server 2008 to locate the problem, but since everything is in aggregate form, it's hard to find the offending asp page.

So I am looking for some troubleshooting tips...

Is there a simple way to check all recent ASP pages and the see amount of time they ran for?

Is there a simple way to see live page requests as they happen?

I basically need to track down this offending code, but I am having a hard time seeing what happening in real-time through IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "W3C Extended Logging" as the log mode for your IIS logfiles, then you can switch on a column "time-taken" which will give you the execution time of each ASP in milliseconds (by default, this column is disabled). [See here](http://www.loganalyzer.net/log-analyzer/w3c-extended.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that something in one application is taking a lock in the database (e.g. through a transaction) and then not releasing it, which causes the other app to timeout.

Check your code for transactions and them being closed, and possibly consdier setting up tracing on the SQL server to log deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to run SQL Server profiler to see what procedure or sql may be taking a long time to execute. You can also use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see any pages that may be taking a long time to finish execution and finally dont forget to check your IIS logs.

Hope that helps